Zooming in/out to highcharts map too slow
I have a problem with zooming in/out with a large number map points in highcharts map.
First of all, I followed this guide:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/mappoint-latlon
After that, I exported my own Custom GeoJSON map following this:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps
And in the end, I inserted a lot of map point with lat/long (1505 in total), and here's the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/mco29/k480sLhb/22/
JSFiddle code is too long to post here.

I added the turboThreshold, also set animation to false, but nothing happened. the problem is the performance of zooming in/out is very slow.
Any ideas ?

You will always have problems trying to display so may markers at once, I would suggest you need Marker Clustering - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/marker-clusters

I'll try, thank you @Mikepote

It works, thank you @Mikepote

Awesome! Glad to hear it
